# How to run batch script in a Jenkins pipeline building on a Windows-based Kubernetes pod

Tags: windows, kubernetes, batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

The following pipeline script is working from my Jenkins instance in Kubernetes:

```
podTemplate(yaml: '''
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: jnlp
    image: jenkins/inbound-agent:nanoserver-1809
  - name: sidecar
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.15-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: windows
''') {
    node(POD_LABEL) {
        container(name: 'sidecar', shell: 'cmd.exe') {
            echo "hello-world"
        }
    }
}
```

However I'm struggling to replace `echo "hello-world"` with a batch script. I've tried
`dir`
`"dir"`
`bat 'dir'`
`bat "dir"`
```` bat ```dir``` ````

The typical error message is

```
[Pipeline] { (hide)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] bat
ERROR: Process exited immediately after creation. See output below
Executing cmd.exe script inside container sidecar of pod simple-batch-44-0z85v-kb7cj-pncc6

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Process exited immediately after creation.
```

What is the correct syntax to execute arbitrary batch commands like "dir"?

Comment: Found the issue. Simply running `dir` or `bat 'dir'` alone fails but will succeed when given a path. For example `bat 'dir c:\\'`. Interestingly PowerShell behaves differently. Running `powershell 'Get-ChildItem'` succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

running `dir` or `bat 'dir'` alone fails but will succeed when given a path.

For example `bat 'dir c:\\'`. Interestingly PowerShell behaves differently. Running `powershell 'Get-ChildItem'` succeeds